# For loop doesn't loop JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, fetch

I have a list of athlete names in JSON format from a fetch. Using for loop, I want to grab all the names under roster > athlete > name and then inserting them into  dropdown menu.

But for some reason the loop is not working. If I take out the loop and just grab a single athlete, it worked. Maybe I got confused about arrays and objects?

JSON code

```
{
    "team": {
        "color": "000000",
        "country": "USA",
        "roster": [
            {
                "athlete": {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "age": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "athlete": {
                    "name": "Jane Doe",
                    "age": 21
                }
            },
            {
                "athlete": {
                    "name": "Jack Doe",
                    "age": 22
                }
            },
            {
                "athlete": {
                    "name": "Joe Doe",
                    "age": 23
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

JS code

```
async function getAthletes() {

    const getPlayers = document.getElementById('getPlayers')

    await fetch('athlete.json', {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        const athletes = data.team.roster[0].athlete

        for(let i = 0; i < athletes.length; i++) {
            getPlayers.innerHTML += `<option value="${athletes[i].name}">${athletes[i].name}</option>`
        }
    }) 
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="getPlayers" data-category="Vote" data-action="click" data-label="Select Player">
    <option value="">Select player</option>
</select>
```

Hoping to get like this after the loop

```
<select id="getPlayers" data-category="pick" data-action="click" data-label="Select Player">
    <option value>Select player</option>
    <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
    <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="Jack Doe">Jack Doe</option>
    <option value="Joe Doe">Joe Doe</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at what you're doing *semantically* here:

```
const athletes = data.team.roster[0].athlete
```

You're creating a variable called *athletes* and setting its value to *an athlete*.  A single instance of something is not a list of something.  In that operation you specify index `0` of the array.  If you want to loop over the entire array, don't use only one of its elements.  Use the entire array:

```
const athletes = data.team.roster;
```

Then each element in the array would be like:

```
{
  "athlete": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 20
  }
}
```

So referencing a value on it in the loop would be something like:

```
athletes[i].athlete.name
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all from your JSON,data.team.roster is the array.
So we have to iterate that array.

JS Code

```
async function getAthletes() {

    const getPlayers = document.getElementById('getPlayers')

    await fetch('athlete.json', {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        const rosters = data.team.roster

        for(let i = 0; i < rosters.length; i++) {
            getPlayers.innerHTML += `<option
       value="${rosters[i].athlete.name}">${rosters[i].athlete.name</option>`
        }
    }) 
}
```

For your other doubt yes u can iterate object also,but with for-in loop or for-each loop or for-of (not with normal FOR).
Arrays can be looped using normal FOR & Foreach.

Answer (score 1):

The `athlete` property is not the array, and has no `.length`. It is `roster` that is the array, which must be iterated. For instance:

```
for (const {athlete: { name }} of data.team.roster) {
    getPlayers.innerHTML += `<option value="${name}">${name}</option>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should grab `team.roster` off the `data` and loop over the values.

Each value should have an `athlete.name` attribute.

```js
const playerSelect = document.getElementById('getPlayers');

// Mock the fetch call
const fetch = async (url, options) => Promise.resolve(({
  json: async () => Promise.resolve({
    "team": {
      "color": "000000",
      "country": "USA",
      "roster": [
        { "athlete": { "name": "John Doe", "age": 20 } },
        { "athlete": { "name": "Jane Doe", "age": 21 } },
        { "athlete": { "name": "Jack Doe", "age": 22 } },
        { "athlete": { "name": "Joe Doe",  "age": 23 } }
      ]
    }
  })
}));

async function getAthletes() {
  await fetch('athlete.json', { method: 'GET' })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ team: { roster } }) => {
      roster.forEach(({ athlete: { name } }) => {
        // DOM manipulation, no hand-written HTML
        playerSelect.append(new Option(name, name));
      });
    });
}

getAthletes(); // Call the async function to populate the select
```

```html
<select id="getPlayers" data-category="Vote" data-action="click" data-label="Select Player">
  <option value="">Select player</option>
</select>
```